# JSDoc - reusing type definitions error (cannot find name ‘type name’)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have the following project structure:

```
api/
  users/
    users.d.js

contexts/
  users/
    users.d.js

utils/
  users/
    users.d.js
```

In *utils/users/users.d.js*
I am defining the types that are reusable through the whole system.

For example, the following type:

```
/**
 * Represents a User.
 *
 * @typedef {object} User
 * @property {string} id - Unique identifier.
 * …
 * @property {Date} birthday - Birthday.
 */
```

This is cool, now I can reuse it in my module *index.js* as follows:

```
import “./utils/users/users.d”;

/**
 * …
 * @param {User} user - The profile owner.
 */
function navigateToUserProfile(user) {
  …
}
```

And that works fine! My code editor detects the type and the documentation can be auto generated without problems :)

But… what if *api/users/users.d.js* requires that global type definition?

For example, what if in that module I have the following definition:

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} EditProfileInterface
 *
 * @property {User} newUserData - The new user data.
 * …
 */
```

In order to reuse the global definition, I would need to import the utility module (*utils/users/users.d.js*) in the “local type definitions” module (*api/users/users.d.js*).

Okey… so, let just do:

```
// this code is inside api/users/users.d.js
import “../../utils/users/users.d”;
```

as we did inside *index.js*.

Here is where my problem comes. After doing this, JSDOC is not able to generate the documentation correctly any more. It moves the type definitions of *api/users/users.d.js* to the **global section** of the documentation.

Also, if I do `// @ts-check` inside a module that imports *api/users/users.d.js*, I get the error **Cannot find name ‘EditProfileInterface’** (unresolved type). This is making really difficult the types reusability… it seems that there is no more options than duplicating the definitions between modules (?)

Any suggestions or workarounds? Should I just don’t care about duplicating type definitions between different modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to configurate JSDoc to support `typescript` mode.

1- Create a `jsconfig.json` file in order to active ts-check in your whole project:

This is the code I use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2021",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "checkJs": true, <--- ACTIVES the @ts-check directive in every single module of your project in order to avoid bugs :) 
  },
  "include": ["app/**/*.d.js", "app/**/*.js", "app/**/*.cjs", "app/**/*.mjs", "app/**/*.jsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "./functions/", "./docs"]
}
```

**If you get a linting error, just re-open VSCode.**

2- Install this development dependency: `jsdoc-tsimport-plugin`

```
yarn add --dev jsdoc-tsimport-plugin
```

3- In your jsdoc config file, add the installed plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "plugins/markdown",
    "node_modules/better-docs/category",
    "node_modules/jsdoc-tsimport-plugin/index.js", <------- THIS!
  ],
  source: {
    include: [
      "Main.jsx",
      "app/",
      "functions/",
      "shared/",
    ],
    includePattern: ".+\\.(js(doc|x)?|(m|c)js)$",
    excludePattern: "(node_modules/|docs)",
  },
  sourceType: "module",
  tags: {
    allowUnknownTags: true,
    dictionaries: ["jsdoc", "closure"],
  },
  ...
```

4- In your eslint configuration file, add the following setting:

```
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-native/all",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
    "plugin:jsdoc/recommended",
  ],
  settings: {
    jsdoc: {
      mode: "typescript", <--- THIS!
    },
  },
  rules: {
  ...
```

**NOW, YOU CAN USE THE TYPESCRIPT SYNTAX WITH JSDOC**

For example, in this project structure:

```
shared/
   types.d.js

api/
   users/
      users.d.js
```

You can define a type in your global types (inside the shared folder):

```
/**
  * Some description for the type definition.
  *
  * @typedef SomeGlobalType
  * @property {string} [text="Hello world"] - Description for the property.
  */
```

And then, simply import it inside `api/users/users.d.js`, like this:

```
 /**
  * @typedef User
  * @property {import("../../shared/types.d").SomeGlobalType} tricky - HEHE 
  */
```

Thats all ;)

Comment: Also, make sure that in your .d.js modules you export something! for example `export {}`, to avoid linting errors.