# React and JSDoc - How to document a React component properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsdoc

I am documenting my **React Native** components, but I don't know how to do it properly.

For the documentation generation, I am using *[jsdoc/better-docs](https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/better-docs)*, which is supposedly able to collect the comments you leave on your `PropTypes` and include them in the documentation. But... due to incompatibility issues, it is not possible to carry out this strategy in React Native, and, therefore, the `PropTypes` **are not included in the documentation**.

How do you document this React component using JSDOC?

```
/**
 * ??
 */
function Cat({ name, color = "#000" }) {
  return <View />;
}

Cat.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  color: PropTypes.string,
};
```

---

I was doing the following:

```
/**
 * The cat properties.
 *
 * @typedef {object} Props
 * @property {string} name - The cat name.
 * @property {string} [color="#000"] - The cat color.
 */

/**
 * Cat component.
 *
 * @type {React.FC<Props>}
 * @returns {React.ReactElement} The cat.
 */
function Cat({ name, color = "#000" }) {
  return <View />;
}

Cat.propTypes = {
  /** The cat name. */
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,

  /** The cat color. */
  color: PropTypes.string,
};
```

But I am feeling that prop-types is useless after adding the type definitions (?).

How do you document your react components?

Comment: Also, if I use a **complete** type definition  in the JSDoc, and (for the same component) a simple `PropTypes.object` in the `component.propTypes`, I get multiple annoying linter warnings, something that makes me doubt about the parallel use of jsdoc and proptypes.

Answer (score 8):

The way to go is to use `InferProps` from `prop-types`. This method is only available for TypeScript :( and I am not using it... instead, I am combining JSDoc and PropTypes in my project to get some "typescript behaviors" in the development experience and auto-generate my documentation.

**BUT THERE IS A WORKAROUND WITHOUT TYPESCRIPT**

Just configure your JSDoc as I described here: [JSDoc - reusing type definitions error (cannot find name ‘type name’)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71149291/jsdoc-reusing-type-definitions-error-cannot-find-name-type-name)

Now, in your code, just do the following:

*components/cat/propTypes.js*:

```
...

export const CatPropTypes = {
   /** The cat data. */
   data: CatDataShape,
   /** The cat name. */
   name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
   /** The cat color. */
   color: PropTypes.string,
};
```

*components/cat/Cat.js*:

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { InferProps } from "prop-types";

import { CatPropTypes } from "./propTypes"; // <-----

/**
 * Cat component.
 *
 * @type {React.FC<InferProps<import("./propTypes").CatPropTypes>>} <---- JSDoc is in TypeScript mode! FANTASTIC! :D
 * @returns {React.ReactElement} The cat.
 */
function Cat({ name, color = "#000" }) {
  return <View />;
}

Cat.propTypes = CatPropTypes; // <-----
```

Now everything is working like a charm and there is no reason to maintain useless JSDoc typedefs! :DDDDDD